# Multiple projects with OpenGrok

Tags: opengrok

I was just wondering what is the best way to setup and configure OpenGrok for multiple projects, e.g. via a single page and a dropdown list.

While the documentation for a single project is pretty straight-forward, the instructions for setting up a multi-project environment isn't very clear to me.

Answer (score 6):

Each directory under SRC_ROOT directory is one project. 
So create your directory structure should look something like this:

```
/opengrok
|-- bin
|-- data
`-- source
   |--project1
   |--project2
   `--project3
```

Then update your index, in this step the configuration.xml file will be updated and each directory under SRC_ROOT (or opengrok/source) will be considered to be a project.

Answer (score 3):

I am on windows and to better handle the situation, I create a consolidated `d:\opengroksrc` folder which contains all my scattered source directories as directory junctions

Example I have a project in d:\gitsrc and another project in d:\hacksrc.
I have created a folder named d:\opengroksrc

`d:\opengroksrc
     '-gitsrc  => hardlink to d:\gitsrc
     '-hacksrc => hardlink to d:\hacksrc`

`mklink /j d:\opengroksrc\gitsrc d:\gitsrc` can be used to create a junction for a directory in windows

and in my `web.xml` I indicate that my source are actually coming from `d:\opengroksrc`

`<context-param>
    <param-name>SRC_ROOT</param-name>
    <param-value>D:\opengroksrc\</param-value>
 </context-param>`

And finally for indexing 
`java -jar E:\opengrok\lib\opengrok.jar -a on -t 4 -W E:\opengrok\configuration.xml -c C:\Windows\ctags.exe -P -S -v -s D:\opengroksrc -d E:\opengrok\grokdata -I *.cs -I *.c -I *.cpp -I *.h -I *.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Go to the directory defined `by OPENGROK_INSTANCE_BASE`(for example: /var/opengrok) and create sub directory 'src' in this path. Then create soft links to your projects like following:

```
cd /var/opengrok/src
ln -s project1 <absolute path of project1>
ln -s project2 <absolute path of project2>
....
```

Finally update index by '`OpenGrok index`'